# Hiding parent react component, when you click on a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to javascript world and creating a front end application using react.js. Following is a scenario I am unable to code. 
I want to display a list of items such that when I click any one item in the list, I ONLY see the details of the chosen item and remove the view of items. I tried to use react-router library, but react-router works in a nested fashion, where details of the child component are rendered under the parent component(the list of items). It does not hide the parent component.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a function to the child `onClick` prop from parent component, and handle the hidden event in that function. A simple implement looks like this:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.state = {hide: false};
    }
    handleChildClick() {
        this.setState({hide: true});
    }
    render() {
        const {hide} = this.state;
        if (hide) {
            return null;
        }
        return <Child onClick={this.handleChildClick.bind(this)} />;
    }
 }

 class Child extends React.Component {
     render() {
         const {onClick} = this.props;
         return <button onClick={onClick}>Hide Parent</button>;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Philip. But, I was able to achieve it in a more clean way using react component **context** attribute. I added an onClick callback(nextPage) to parent element.                                                                                  /* onClick callback*/                                                                           nextPage() {
    let url = <url_value>
    this.context.router.push(url);
  }  /* Declare the context */ <React Component Name>.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};